# Can anyone identify this strangely shaped piece (1970s?)

Tags: part-identification, vintage

I bought a tin of old Lego second hand - most of the pieces date from the 70s and very early 80s. These definitely say Lego on them. They may be damaged. I cannot find them on other brick identifier sites. Can anyone help?

[image]

All help gratefully received. The image isn't great but they are the classic red colour. The holes in the side fit the old style metal pins in Lego wheels.

Comment: Sadly those rough spots are where plastic pins used to stick out but they're been broken off your parts. Those were part of the support/tipping mechanism on the train model.

Comment: http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/125/Tipper_wagon has a good example (picture) of how those parts are used.

Answer (score 10):

It's a "[Vehicle, Tipper End Flat with Pins](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3145)". It was used in trains (but not only trains) a long time ago (1969-1982), and I actually have a couple from a train I owned as a kid.

Comment: Thank you. I did wonder if they were train related. Thanks for the Bricklink reference. I hadn't been able to find them.

Answer (score 9):

They're part of the 1972 train-sets 130, 171, 180, 181 and 724 (picture is set 130)

[image: 130]

Yellow version is part of the 1979 technic-set 856.

[image: 856]

Answer (score 3):

We had a couple of yellow ones of these. Used for mounting snow plough blades onto the front of the Unimog kit.

Comment: I have the Unimog set, but it definitely did not include any parts like this, neither in red nor in yellow. After looking through the official snow plough instructions, I also never saw them being used.

Comment: I guess Jono is referring to an older Unimog-set. The 1981 set 8848. ![lego 8848](http://media.peeron.com/pics/inv/setpics/8848-1.1119047204.thumb2.jpg)

Comment: Oh, so there was an older Unimog... Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I have two red ones which I got in a lot of Vintage LEGO, since there were many parts of vintage train stuff in the same lot like the blue train tracks, my guess is that they are parts to the train lego, I could imagine that they were suppose to be parts making up a tipping container...